# Fixed Top Navbar not working in Angular10

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I currently have a single HTML page that has multiple sections, and options in the main navbar enable users to navigate / scroll to the appropriate section. The styling has been achieved using Bootstrap4 and custom CSS.

I'm now trying to replicate the same behavior in an Angular 10 application. I have setup routing and created a 'home' component. The homecomponent.html is as follows:

```
<!-- ======= Header (Main Navbar) ======= -->
<header id="header" class="header fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid container-xl d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">

      <a href="index.html" class="logo d-flex align-items-center">
        <img src="assets/img/Monkish_Icon_Small.png" alt="">
        <span>Monkish</span>
      </a>

      <nav id="navbar" class="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto active" href="#hero">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#services">Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <i class="bi bi-list mobile-nav-toggle"></i>
      </nav><!-- .navbar -->

    </div>
  </header><!-- End Header -->

<!-- ======= Hero Section ======= -->
<section id="hero" class="hero d-flex align-items-center">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
        <h1 data-aos="fade-up">Holistic Wellness & You</h1>
        <h2 data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="600">We leverage modern science, and traditional wisdom to help you eat, move and live better</h2>
        <div data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="700">
          <div class="text-center text-lg-start">
            <a href="#services" class="btn-get-started scrollto d-inline-flex align-items-center justify-content-center align-self-center">
              <span>Get Started</span>
              <i class="bi bi-arrow-right"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 hero-img" data-aos="zoom-out" data-aos-delay="400">
        <img src="assets/img/Banner_Small.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section><!-- End Hero -->

<main id="main">

  <!-- ======= Services Section ======= -->
  <section id="services" class="services">

    <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">

      <header class="section-header">
        <h2>Services</h2>
        <p>Given the current covid situation in India, we are providing free diet plans</p>
      </header>


      <div class="row gy-4">

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">
          <div class="service-box blue">
            <i class="ri-discuss-line icon"></i>
            <h3>Immunity Booster Plan</h3>
            <p>Provident nihil minus qui consequatur non omnis maiores. Eos accusantium minus dolores iure perferendis tempore et consequatur.</p>
            <a href="#" class="read-more"><span>Get It</span> <i class="bi bi-arrow-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="300">
          <div class="service-box orange">
            <i class="ri-discuss-line icon"></i>
            <h3>Post Vaccination Plan</h3>
            <p>Ut autem aut autem non a. Sint sint sit facilis nam iusto sint. Libero corrupti neque eum hic non ut nesciunt dolorem.</p>
            <a href="#" class="read-more"><span>Get It</span> <i class="bi bi-arrow-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="400">
          <div class="service-box green">
            <i class="ri-discuss-line icon"></i>
            <h3>Ledo Markt</h3>
            <p>Ut excepturi voluptatem nisi sed. Quidem fuga consequatur. Minus ea aut. Vel qui id voluptas adipisci eos earum corrupti.</p>
            <a href="#" class="read-more"><span>Get It</span> <i class="bi bi-arrow-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </section><!-- End Services Section -->
</main><!-- End #main -->
```

The AppComponent.html is as follows:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The 'header' class is specified in the styles.css as follows:

```
.header {
    transition: all 0.5s;
    z-index: 997;
    padding: 20px 0;
  }
```

The app-routing.module.ts is as follows:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And finally, the app.module.ts is as follows:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The issue I face is that the main navbar (header in homecomponent.html), although remains fixed at the top, does not loose transparency when I navigate to another section or scroll down on the page. Section contents are still visible behind the navbar if I scroll down.

This works perfectly on the standard HTML page wherein the navbar takes on a solid color based on scrolling / navigation. I'm still new to angular and assume that this issue might be related to hierarchy of components and / or heights of components. Can someone please help me with this. I can share more of the custom CSS rules if needed.

Many Thanks

Comment: It could be that the CSS rules defined in styles.css aren't reaching the header in homecomponent due to Angular [component style](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles) encapsulation. When you inspect the `.header` element, are the CSS rules you expect to be applied not actually there? The styles you want applied to homecomponent elements should be defined in homecomponent's styles. Alternatively, you can use `::ng-deep` to force external styles to apply to the component's internal elements.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this and give you an update.

Answer (score 1):

Implement separate components.
Create a header component.

Import it in your app.module.ts file

```
import { HeaderModule } from '../header.component'
```

And then add it in your home.html file

```
<app-header></app-header>
```

Now header is a separate component and will not rerender again.
You can now send routes from header to the home component.